# Writing a function with four arguments

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to solve this problem:

We define objects called (p.q) numbers. In R the (p,q) numbers are lists with four elements. The first element of the list is either the integer +1+1 or the integer −1−1. It gives the sign of the number. The second and third element are p and q, each a non-negative integer. And the fourth element is a vector of p+q+1 integers between zero and nine.

Write a function which takes the four arguments sign, p, q, and nums. Then check if the arguments satisfy all requirements for a (p,q) number. If not, stop with an error message. If yes, return the (p.q) number as a list with attribute pqNumber using the structure() function.

Here's my code so far. I'm not sure what's wrong or what I need to do.

```
`pqNumber <- function(sign, p, q, nums) {
  nums <- c()
  if (sign != 1 && sign != -1) stop ("sign must be 1 or -1")
  if (round != p) stop ("p must be an integer")
  if (round != q) stop ("q must be an integer")
  if (p < 0) stop ("p cannot be negative")
  if (q < 0) stop ("q cannot be negative")
  if (length(nums) != p + q + 1) stop ("nums must be a vector of p+q+1 integers")
  structure(list(sign = sign, p = p, q = q, nums = nums), class = "pqNumber")
}`
```

Comment: You are not applying the `round` function to anything. And I think you should look again at the first conditional.

Comment: Would i use !is.integer(p) instead of round?

Comment: Look at the result of `is.integer(1)`

Comment: This sort of code is best done using the *assertive* package.  `assert_all_are_whole_numbers(p)`, `assert_all_are_positive(p)`, etc.

Comment: So there's no built in function in R that checks for an integer?